# Function that helps with reaching nested objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
/**
 * Returns the value of a nested property of source object if it exists.
 * Even if the nested property evaluates to false it will be returned.
 * If the nested property does not exist, undefined will be returned.
 * @param {Object} source       source object
 * @param {String} path         path without first dot e.g. "response.http.statusCode"
 * @param {String=} sourceName  if provided, any catched error will be logged to console
 * @returns {*}                 value under the source.path or undefined
 */
function reach(source, path, sourceName) {
    var result;
    try {
        if (sourceName) {
            eval('var ' + sourceName + '=source; result=' + sourceName + '.' + path);
        } else {
            eval('result=source.' + path);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        if (sourceName) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I know that `eval` is dangerous, but I made the assumption that it's the caller's responsibility.

Comment: I'm unclear why this is needed  or useful or what problem you're trying to solve?  Under what circumstance is a path like `response.http.statusCode` in a string variable and not something you can just code directly?

Comment: Are you writing a compiler or something?

Comment: @Jfriend I if response does not exist, by calling `let code = response.http.statusCode` I would get the familiar `cannot read property "http" of undefined` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to an earlier [answer I did](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/125510/11919) with regards to deep value extraction. Here's the code:

```
function createResolver(keypath){
  return new Function('root', `
    try { return root.${keypath}; }
    catch(e){ return undefined; }
 `);
}

// Return foo.bar.baz
var obj1 = { foo: { bar: { baz: 'bam!!!' }}};
var resolver1 = createResolver('foo.bar.baz');
var value1 = resolver1(obj1);
```

One difference between this one and your approach is that your approach seems to evaluate on every call. This can be slow as you are having the browser evaluate the string JavaScript on every call. A constructed function on the other hand can be cached. This means you can construct the function once, store the constructed function, and call it over and over again without having to re-evaluate the string every time.

```
// keypath-resolver store
var resolvers = {}

function createResolver(keypath){
  return new Function('root', `
    try { return root.${keypath}; }
    catch(e){ return undefined; }
 `);
}

// Create a resolver for foo.bar.baz. We only have JS evaluate the string here.
resolvers['foo.bar.baz'] = createResolver('foo.bar.baz');

var obj1 = { foo: { bar: { baz: 'bam!!!' }}};
var obj2 = { foo: { bar: { baz: 'pow!!!' }}};

// We just call the function. No evaluation!
resolvers['foo.bar.baz'](obj1);
resolvers['foo.bar.baz'](obj2);
```

Although these two approaches seem to act the same, one issue with `eval` is that it evaluates the string in the scope it is called. This means it can leak variables or override code that's visible in the current scope, just like you did with `result`. A generated function on the other hand does not. It does not form a closure of the scope it was created from, and the immediate outer scope is the global scope. This makes it relatively safer than `eval`.

Your reliance of `console.log` is also something to ponder on. If it's an error, is it not better to actually throw than just log the error? Also, if the keypath isn't fully resolved, this means the value isn't present which makes it technically `undefined`. Consider returning `undefined` instead of logging an error if you want errors to be handled.

Comment: This implementation is very good. I created a small benchmark

Comment: My implementation:
`reach-deep for existing property invoked 100000 times: 46.194ms`
`reach-deep for existing property invoked 100000 times: 52.614ms`

Comment: @josephSilber 's implementation:
`reachAlternative for existing property invoked 100000 times: 143.837ms` 
`reachAlternative for non-existing property invoked 100000 times: 164.550ms`

Comment: Popular npm package that solves this problem:
`reach for existing property invoked 100000 times: 271.807ms` 
`reach for non-existing property invoked 100000 times: 271.707ms`

Comment: Joseph the Dreamer's implementation
`resolver for existing property invoked 100000 times: 4.460ms`
`resolver for non-existing property invoked 100000 times: 14.469ms`

Comment: Cleary the last one is the best :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I would improve:

1. Don't use `eval`, even if you think that in this particular case it's safe. Even if it were, it's still slow, and not supported everywhere JS is.
2. There's no point in using this function if you know that the path exists. The whole point is to try to fetch something through a deep path without an error. I think you can skip the console logging bit.
3. It'd make sense to allow the user to provide a default value to be returned if the final path segment is not found.
4. If you're doing this, you may as well support arrays too.

---

In light of the above, here's what I'd do:

```js
function reach (source, path, replacement) {
    var key;

    if ( ! Array.isArray(path)) {
        path = path.split('.');
    }

    while (key = path.shift()) {
        if (Array.isArray(source)) {
            if (isNaN(key) || typeof source[key] === 'undefined') {
                return replacement;
            }

            source = source[key];
        } else if (source && source.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            source = source[key];
        } else {
            return replacement;
        }
    }

    return source;
}
```

[Here's how to use it](http://codepen.io/JosephSilber/pen/mPKdvd?editors=0011):

```js
const source = {
    build: {
        house: {
            types: ['Stone', 'Bricks']
         }
    }
};

reach(source , 'build.house') // { types: ['Stone', 'Bricks'] }
reach(source , 'build.house.types') // ['Stone', 'Bricks']
reach(source , 'build.house.types.length') // undefined
reach(source , 'build.house.types.1') // 'Bricks'
reach(source , 'build.cot.types.1') // undefined
reach(source , 'build.cot.types.1', 'Wood') // 'Wood'
```

Comment: Thiw would not work for objects that are hidden inside a function.

Comment: Also this implementation is about 3 times slower for existing paths, and 30% slower for non existing.

Comment: @JanOsch - what do you mean by "hidden inside a function"?

Comment: As for the speed: if that's your main concern, you could probably speed this thing up significantly if you replace `while (key = path.shift())` with a `for` loop. Messing with the array like that is pretty expensive.

Comment: I checked the implementation with a `for(;;)` loop, and it's still more than 2 times slower than my original.

Comment: By hidden inside a function I mean a path that contains a function call `var result = reach(mock, 'a().b.c[1]["d"].e')`